# glib scheduler in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, glib

I am trying to unit test some scheduler calls.  I create a timeout which needs to call a callback some time later.  However, I do not want to start and stop the scheduler in the test.  So, I thought I could cleverly use `main_context.pending()` for this. However, I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
import glib
import gobject

def ook():
    print('Stup!d monkey')
    return False

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
glib.timeout_add(100, ook)
```

When I add and run the code below, nothing is ever printed.

```
main_context = glib.MainLoop.get_context(loop)
while main_context.pending():
    main_context.iteration(False)
```

When I add and run the code below, the string is indeed printed.

```
loop.run()
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation for g_main_context_pending](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-pending), it

> Checks if any sources have pending events for the given context.

Your timeout source will not have any pending events until after the 100ms has passed.  Until then, it will merely have a source with no pending events attached to it.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if there will be pending events in a source at a given time?  Otherwise, it makes testing your code that relies on the scheduler impossible unless you run the scheduler for real!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Timeouts aren't the only event sources—they're probably not even the most common ones, and it's impossible to know whether anything other than timeout sources will have pending events at some point in the future.  Even with timeouts it's not really precise...  I don't see how you could usefully test it without running the loop, and I can't think of a good reason not to run it.